# What is the rotation number of differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms, line-integrals

I saw the definition of rotation number in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103365/equivalence-between-statements-of-hodge-conjecture) about differential forms. Here it is for convenience.

> A complex differential $k$-form $\omega$ has rotation number $p-q$ if
>
> $$\omega (e^{i\theta} v_1, \dots, e^{i\theta} v_k) = e^{(p-q)i \theta} \omega (v_1, \dots, v_k),$$
>
> with $p+q=k$.

I am wondering what the intuitive explanation for this is. For instance, suppose we have a one form in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\alpha = a \, dx + b \, dy + c \, dz$. Then we can (loosely) think of $\alpha$ as the vector field:

$$\mathbf{F} = a \, \hat{i} + b \, \hat{j} + c \, \hat{z},  $$

(given that the line integral of the field $\mathbf{F}$ over a curve $C$ is the equal to the integral of the differential form $\alpha$ over $C$.)

Here is my question: **If $\alpha$ has rotation number zero, does it say anything about the physical nature of the vector field $\mathbf{F}$?** For example, does the vector field not change under rotation, or does it have no curl, etc.? I'm looking for a way to make the abstract "rotation number" definition more visual and tangible. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is defined for differential forms on a complex manifold, where differential forms have type $(p,q)$, comprised of (smooth) linear combinations of the wedge product of $p$ $dz^j$'s and $q$ $d\bar z^k$'s. On $\Bbb C$, the $1$-form $dz$ has rotation number $1$ and the $1$-form $d\bar z$ has rotation number $-1$.

Comment: Ah yes, that really clarifies things. As a follow up: is there any geometric intuition for why it is called a rotation number? When we say that $dz$ has rotation number $1$, for example, how can we interpret that more geometrically/tangibly? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have never heard of this before, but I would hazard a guess that with the usual complex structure we have rotation number $1$ when we go once around the unit circle counterclockwise, whereas with the conjugate complex structure we have rotation number $-1$. You'd need to ask the folks who invented the terminology. :)